# Are run-on sentences always bad?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry, sentence-structure

(TW, depression related stuff?)

In my AP Lang class, we've recently started an activity called Visiting Author, where a student does a cold read of a piece they wrote and the others give criticism and suggestions either out loud or on paper.  I volunteered to read a poem I had written about my life.  Afterwards, during the suggestions and reading over people's thoughts, I noticed a few people criticized my use of run-on sentences.

Example One, directly from my piece:

> i vomited up equations and
>
> heaved tears into my pillows
>
> when i heard my mother say,
>
> "i'm disappointed,"
>
> because the numbers always needed
>
> to be higher
>
> except when it came to the
>
> milligrams of medication,
>
> pulvules of prozac replacing my pupils,
>
> dependency on my happy pills
>
> does not dare affect
>
> the prodigy.

Example Two:

> coddled by trauma, taught to walk
>
> by mental breakdowns mislabeled as
>
> temper tantrums,
>
> and at the tender age of nine
>
> in the fifth house i'd lived in
>
> the manifestations of my illness
>
> wrapped a belt around my neck
>
> and tried to silence me,
>
> but i didn't have time.

Are these sentences "bad", or confusing?  Are run-ons always a bad idea, or can they be effective?  Is my use of run-on sentences effective?

Comment: I see fragments and run ons used in published fiction and contributing to 'voice.' I believe they must be used intentionally for a specific effect.

Comment: I agree with DPT. As long as it there for a purpose, it's fine. Especially in poetry - some of my favorite poets don't use punctuation at all. In this case, it gives a sense of endlessness, breathlessness, you can't pause to think. It gives the reader a taste of the way you feel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run on sentences are sentences without a pause.  No place to take a breath.

By using what might otherwise be a run on sentence as free verse poetry, you are creating those pauses.

You have some commas in there, which always helps, but it's the line breaks that really give you a place to breathe.  Commas alone (or commas plus dashes and semi-colons) aren't enough breathing space for a very long expression.  You need those periods.  A line break (or stanza break) isn't punctuation per say, but it acts as such in a poem.

Poems don't have to conform to the same grammar restrictions of prose.

Giving the illusion of a single thought without a break, while simultaneously providing those breaks, is a very effective use of language.

Answer (score 2):

BLUF: run-on sentences aren't necessarily a bad thing. LOTS of run -ons, however, are very distracting.

I teach acting, and we often do cold reads. Some of my students are "Grammar Nazis." I tell them that the written word has rules of grammar. The spoken word has rules of grammar, which differ from those of written grammar.

Not being a poetry person, I am still inclined to say that poetry has its own form of grammar.

Whenever possible, I have my students critique each other, just as your English teacher has done. It is a very useful tool. Your post reminds me of some things I have heard in my classes. This is what I say:
Was this their honest opinion, or were they being jerks?
Oftentimes, someone will make a comment that is an honest opinion, but not worded well.

Ex: "You have a run on sentence," could actually mean "That sentence was so long and confusing I couldn't understand it."
The latter is a very useful comment. As a writer, don't you want your audience to understand what you have written?

It is also possible that the comment came from a person who really is a Grammar Nazi and won't be happy with it unless it is formatted EXACTLY the way he/she thinks it should be.

What I read in your question is that you may be bothered by their comments. If so, that is an indication that you know *something* is not quite right about that passage. In which case, re-write it and/or ask other people about it until it "feels" right to you.

So, to answer your question, run-on sentences aren't necessarily a bad thing. LOTS of run -ons, however, are very distracting.

Comment: Welcome to the Writing Stack Exchange!  Just a soft recommendation -- echo your last line (the yes/no answer) at the top of your answer.  You certainly don't have to -- that is really just a recommendation based on my own preferences.  I think it makes for a better answer.